# IIS Rewrite Module and sub applications / React-Router

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, react-router

Ok, this is similar to other questions out there but I am not familiar with url rewrite.

I am hosting (hopefully only for development and testing) a react application under IIS.

If hosted in the root of the site folder all is well using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But I need it to work in a subapplication. For instance: http://myserver:8888/myapp. Where myapp is the sub application.

IIS diagram:

Sites
- MySite
  - MyApp

Better example of the url that includes the route:  http://myserver:8888/myapp/1234/abcd.
1234 and abcd are route values/params.

```
contents of my app directory are:
   index.html
   main.a9e1df0325f4fdb57e7e.js
   vendors~main.c8848853e10f698af19d.js
   web.config
```

Thanks

Gina

Answer (score 0):

You could host your app in any subapplication in iis but be careful to defining correct route for serving contents. It seems you want to host static content so you can't use route parameters in url hence these parameters are used by asp.net. Static content are served by iis. You can try this url for serving content in **myapp**:

```
http://myserver:8888/myapp/index.html
```

Comment: I know how to host a normal application as a subapp in IIS. My difficulty here is a react app.